# Как добавить Атрибуты страницы с произвольном типе записей WordPress

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вывел произвольный тип записи, после этого написал singe-page для этого типа записи, столкнулся с тем, что в хлебных крошках не отображается цепочка, а только ссылка на главную. Думаю что нужно выбрать родительскую страницу для этой записи, но в админке нет селекта с атрибутами страницы. Подскажите, как добавить этот параметр в админку, или как вывести хлебные крошки для произвольного типа записей?

```
// Регистрируем тип произвольных записей
    add_action('init', 'register_post_types');
    function register_post_types()
    {
        register_post_type('post_type_1', array(
            'label' => null,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Спецтехника', // основное название для типа записи
                'singular_name' => '____', // название для одной записи этого типа
                'add_new' => 'Добавить позицию', // для добавления новой записи
                'add_new_item' => 'Добавление позиции', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
                'edit_item' => 'Редактирование позиции', // для редактирования типа записи
                'new_item' => 'Новая позиция', // текст новой записи
                'view_item' => 'Смотреть позицию', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
                'search_items' => 'Искать позицию', // для поиска по этим типам записи
                'not_found' => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
                'parent_item_colon' => 'post_type_1', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
                'menu_name' => 'Спецтехника', // название меню
            ),
            'description' => '',
            'public' => true,
            // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
            // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
            'show_in_menu' => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
            // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
            'show_in_rest' => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
            'rest_base' => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
            'menu_position' => null,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-dashboard',
            //'capability_type'   => 'post',
            //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
            'map_meta_cap' => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'supports' => ['title', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'editor', 'page-attributes'], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive' => false,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
        ));
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    }

// Breadcrumb

/**
 * Retrieve category parents.
 *
 * @param int $id Category ID.
 * @param array $visited Optional. Already linked to categories to prevent duplicates.
 * @return string|WP_Error A list of category parents on success, WP_Error on failure.
 */
function custom_get_category_parents( $id, $visited = array() ) {
    $chain = '';
    $parent = get_term( $id, 'category' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
        return $parent;

    $name = $parent->name;

    if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id ) && !in_array( $parent->parent, $visited ) ) {
        $visited[] = $parent->parent;
        $chain .= custom_get_category_parents( $parent->parent, $visited );
    }

    $chain .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $parent->term_id ) ) . '">' . $name. '</a>' . '</li>';

    return $chain;
}
function bootstrap_breadcrumb() {
    global $post;

    $html = '<ol class="breadcrumb">';

    if ( (is_front_page()) || (is_home()) ) {
        $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">Главная</li>';
    }

    else {
        $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="'.esc_url(home_url('/')).'">Главная</a></li>';

        if ( is_attachment() ) {
            $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
            $categories = get_the_category($parent->ID);

            if ( $categories[0] ) {
                $html .= custom_get_category_parents($categories[0]);
            }

            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $parent ) ) . '">' . $parent->post_title . '</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_category() ) {
            $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );

            if ( $category->parent != 0 ) {
                $html .= custom_get_category_parents( $category->parent );
            }

            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_page() && !is_front_page() ) {
            $parent_id = $post->post_parent;
            $parent_pages = array();

            while ( $parent_id ) {
                $page = get_page($parent_id);
                $parent_pages[] = $page;
                $parent_id = $page->post_parent;
            }

            $parent_pages = array_reverse( $parent_pages );

            if ( !empty( $parent_pages ) ) {
                foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent ) {
                    $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $parent->ID ) ) . '">' . get_the_title( $parent->ID ) . '</a></li>';
                }
            }

            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
            $categories = get_the_category();

            if ( $categories[0] ) {
                $html .= custom_get_category_parents($categories[0]);
            }

            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_tag() ) {
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_day() ) {
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_year_link( get_the_time( 'Y' ) ) ) . '">' . get_the_time( 'Y' ) . '</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_month_link( get_the_time( 'Y' ), get_the_time( 'm' ) ) ) . '">' . get_the_time( 'm' ) . '</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_time('d') . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_month() ) {
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="' . esc_url( get_year_link( get_the_time( 'Y' ) ) ) . '">' . get_the_time( 'Y' ) . '</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_time( 'F' ) . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_year() ) {
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_time( 'Y' ) . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_author() ) {
            $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item active">' . get_the_author() . '</li>';
        }

        elseif ( is_search() ) {

        }

        elseif ( is_404() ) {

        }

    }

    $html .= '</ol>';

    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

За вложенность произвольных типов отвечает параметр:

```
'hierarchical' => true
'supports'     => array( ..., 'page-attributes' ),
```

Каким образом вы водите хлебные крошки?

Comment: Я использую готовое ришение, так как использую bootstrap
<?php bootstrap_breadcrumb(); ?>

Comment: Если тебе нужно вложенность пост типов, то тебе нужен hierarchical. Но возможно тебе так же нужна кастомная таксономия?

Comment: Добавил в код пример как я вывожу хлебные крошки

Comment: Ты можешь как угодно сделать хлебные крошки поправив свою функцию bootstrap_breadcrumb

Comment: Как поправить ее подскажите плиз, ато я уже час сижу над этой проблемой с крошками?

Comment: Конкретно какая задача у вас стоит? Вы сейчас реализовали вложенность пост типа и хотите выводить родительский пост тип, так?

Comment: Да я сделал пост тип и сингл пейдж этого типа, но когда я перехожу в синг пйдж этого типа, в крошках отображается только ссылка на главную, но мне нужно чтобы было типо так(Главная => Каталог => Имя поста)

Comment: elseif ( is_singular( 'your-custom-post-type' ) ) {

Comment: Теперь выводится (Главная => Имя поста) , А мне нужно чтобы было (Главная => Каталог => Имя поста)
Для этого нужно я так понимаю нужно указать родительскую страницу, но указать я ее не могу так-как в списке Родительских страниц ее нету, а есть только такие-же посты

Comment: У всех ваших кастомных типов будет 1 конкретная страница?

Comment: elseif ( is_singular( 'your-custom-post-type' )  ) { 
    $html .= '<li class="breadcrumb-item">' . get_the_title(37) . '</li>';
}
Вместо 37 поставьте id вашей страницы "Каталог"
Вместо your-custom-post-type поставьте реальный слаг вашего пост типа

Comment: Ну будет не 1 конкретная страница, по идеи в Админке нужно указывать на родителя, но как я писал выще проблема в том что Родительские страницы не отображаются, проблема собственно я думаю в этом

Comment: Также во время объявления произвольного типа записи есть такой пункт
'parent_item_colon' => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
Возможно нужно вписать что-то в эту строку чтобы родительские страницы подтянулись?

Comment: Мне кажется я понял, обновил свой ответ. Так же на странице редактирования поста вверху есть "Настройки экрана" там нужно отметить галочкой "Атрибуты страницы"

Comment: Они отмечены, и этот селект работает, но в выборе нету тех страниц которые мне нужны

Comment: Все, понял. Вы хотите связать кастомный тип постов с обычными страницами?

Comment: Да, нужно так сделать

Comment: Тогда с помощью плагина ACF добавь поле для связи вашего типа постов с обычными страницами и потом в хлебных крошках получай это дополнительное поле

Comment: Прикрепил криншот как это выглядит у меня в Админ панели

Comment: А без плагина можно ли это связать?